# php mail not showing senders email address

Tags: php

I¨ve got a problem answering mails sent from my website, as the senders emailaddress isn´t showing anywhere, only the webmasters email

Here is my code:

```
<?php> 
$from="kim.s.nielsen@mail.dk"; 
$email="info@intotext.dk"; 
$name=$_POST['name']; 
$message=$_POST['message']; 
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

$headers .= 'From: ' . $fromName . ' <' . $fromEmail .'>' . " \r\n" . 'Reply-To: '. $fromEmail . "\r\n" . mail($email, $name, $message, $headers); 

print"Din besked er sendt. Vi vender tilbage så hurtigt som muligt." ?>
```

Comment: Syntax error on line 17. /s ... what do you expect from us? How shall we help you, when you can't even show us your code? Thats like "hey men, my car isn't working. Pls fix it. Oh btw, I can't show you my car. But I swear it isn't working. Can you plz tell me why?"

Comment: Not sure I understand.

Comment: I ask you what do you want from us? We can't help you when you don't show us your code.

Comment: <?php>

$from="kim.s.nielsen@mail.dk";
$email="info@intotext.dk";
$name=$_POST['name'];
$message=$_POST['message'];



$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:  ' . $fromName . ' <' . $fromEmail .'>' . " \r\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' . $fromEmail . "\r\n" .


mail($email, $name, $message, $headers);
 
print"Din besked er sendt. Vi vender tilbage så hurtigt som muligt."



?>

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the code there. It is not readable when pasted into a comment like you did.

Comment: Simply accept my edit. I've dont it. Btw you code fails because your variable names. On the top you used `$from` and then later you're refering to it as `$fromName` respectivly `$fromEmail` - those vars are not even defined in your code.

Comment: Instead of trying to create your own e-mail wrapper it's adviced to use a library such as `phpmailer` or  `swiftmailer`

Answer (score 0):

Use this format to send your email, this will show the senders email address, try this. you have concatenated the mail function with your header, mail() is not header it is used to send your email.

```
$fullname = "full name";
$from = "sender@mail";
$to = "reciever@mail";
$subject = "Your subject";
$message = "<h1> heading </h1><p> Message </p>";

$headers = [
    'MIME-Version: 1.0',
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1',
    'From: ' . htmlspecialchars($fullname) . " <$from>",
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()
];

mail($to,
     htmlspecialchars($subject),
     nl2br(htmlspecialchars($message)),
     implode("\r\n", $headers)
);
```

Comment: I can´t seem to get it working.Still only seeing webmaster address,

Comment: Are you getting the mail in browser if yes show me the pic to know what exactly is the problem

Comment: I am but it doesn´t matter where I get the mail. Its still the webaster email showing.

Comment: Are u using it on localhost with xamp if yes then u have to set it up in the settings and where are u recieving emails

Comment: I am not using localhost.

Comment: Have u enabled email settings from mercury xamp plz search how to enable i am afk